# Zak transform and VMO

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

The Zak transform of a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)\cap L^2(\mathbb R)$ is defined as follows:
$$
Zf(x,\omega) := \sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}f(x+k)e^{-2\pi i k\omega},\quad (x,\omega)\in Q_0 :=(0,1)^2.
$$
This is well-defined, since the series converges absolutely almost everywhere. It can be shown that the operator $Z$ defined above is an isometry (mapping to $L^2(Q_0)$) and that it extends to a unitary operator between $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $L^2(Q_0)$. The function $Zf$ is often also extended quasi-periodically to a function in $L^2_{\rm loc}(\mathbb R^2)$.

There are some well known connections between $f,\hat f$ and $Zf$. For example $f,\hat f\in H^1(\mathbb R)$ if and only if $Zf\in H^1_{\rm loc}(\mathbb R^2)$. Or $Zf\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ if and only if $f\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ (the Schwartz class). Also, if $f$ is continuous and in the Wiener space, then $Zf$ is continuous.

Here, we are dealing with functions that are VMO (for the definition and some characterizing conditions see, e.g., http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-207-00/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3/S0002-9947-1975-0377518-3.pdf). We could prove that $Zf\in\operatorname{VMO}(\mathbb R^2)$ implies that both $f,\hat f\in\operatorname{VMO}(\mathbb R)$ (where $\hat f$ denotes the Fourier transform of $f$). However, we are not sure whether the converse holds true. In other words, *our question is what $f,\hat f\in\operatorname{VMO}(\mathbb R)$ implies for $Zf$*. As a start, we figured out that if $Q$ is a square with center $(x_0,\omega_0)\in\mathbb R^2$ and sidelength $\delta$ and $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, then the average $(Zf)_Q$ of $Zf$ over $Q$ satisfies $(Zf)_Q= Zg(x_0,\omega_0)$, where
$$
g(x) = \operatorname{sinc}(\delta(x-x_0))\cdot\tfrac 1 \delta\int_{-\delta/2}^{\delta/2}f(x+t)\,dt.
$$
As $g$ is continuous and can be shown to be an element of the Wiener space, $Zg$ is continuous.

Maybe it is worth mentioning that Gautam proved in 2008 that $f\in H^{p/2}(\mathbb R)$ and $\hat f\in H^{q/2}(\mathbb R)$ (where $\tfrac 1 p+\tfrac 1 q = 1$) implies $Zf\in\operatorname{VMO}(\mathbb R^2)$ (see https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ddb2/dd928eb69a5399b81c96b2a1d283eb85b8c4.pdf).

This is all we have for the moment and we got stuck. So, if anybody knows anything on this or would like to collaborate, we would be very happy.

Comment: Let me try to understand something. One can easily create smooth functions of $L^2$-norm $1$ such that both $f$ and $\widehat f$ are as small in $L^\infty$ as you wish. Using them as "bumps" and shifting them sufficiently far every time, we can make a sequence $f_n$ such that $f_n$ and $\widehat f_n$ have uniform control in $VMO$ but grow without bound in $L^2(\mathbb R)$. Then $Zf_n$ grow in $L^2(Q_0)$ which makes the question "what does $f,\widehat f\in VMO$ imply for $Zf$?" ill-posed at least somewhat. Can you elaborate on what the rigorous formulation of that question is?

Comment: You are right. The question is not posed very precisely. Actually, we are hoping that $f,\hat f\in\operatorname{VMO}$ if and only if $Zf\in\operatorname{VMO}_{\rm loc}$ (at least when $f,\hat f,Zf$ are assumed to be $L^\infty$). Since $\operatorname{VMO}$ and $\operatorname{BMO}$ do not take care of the "size" of the function, your example does at least not exclude that $Zf_n\in\operatorname{VMO}$.

Comment: They do, provided that the means are under control, which is pretty easy to ensure in my example (say, the global mean is  controlled just by $\int_0^1 f_n$, which stays bounded independently of $n$ if the bumps escape to the right or just if the sum of their $L^\infty$ norms is finite), so I'm still confused about what exactly you may hope for here. Though, of course, the assumption $Zf\in L^\infty$ should help a lot. Just post a clear "yes/no" question and I'll think of it :-)